# Number of spanning trees in cycle graphs joined together

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, trees

Two cycle graphs $C_{n}$ and $C_{m}$ are joined together:

1. with a vertex,
2. with an edge.

What is the number of spanning trees in the new graph?

I think I've worked out the answer to question 1, as there are $n$ possible edges to be removed from $C_{n}$, $m$ to be removed form $C_{m}$ and the rest form a unique spanning tree, so the answer is $n \cdot m$. But I'd appreciate any help with question 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: You’re right about the first problem. For the second you have to consider two possibilities:

- If you remove the common edge, you have an $(m+n-1)$-cycle. What must you do now to get a spanning tree?
- If you keep the common edge, you have to break each of the two cycles by removing one of its *other* edges.

Count the spanning trees in each case and add the results to get the final answer.

Comment: In the first case I have to remove one of the edges, which makes the number of possibilities $m+n-2$. And in the second case I have to calculate the total number of ways I can mix $(m-1)$ egdes with $(n-1)$ edges, that's $(m-1) \cdot (n-1)$. Summing up, $m \cdot n - 1$ spanning trees. Thank you a lot!

Comment: @Theta: Almost: in the first case there are $m+n-1$ possible edges to remove, not $m+n-2$. You’re welcome!

Comment: Hmm, are you qsure? I'm inclined to think that the common edge is included both in $C_{n}$ and $C_{m}$, shouldn't it be subtracted twice?

Comment: @Theta: You’re right: I was inadvertently counting the edges in the whole graph. My apologies!

Comment: It's perfectly ok, thanks once again!

Comment: @Theta: My pleasure.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if you are still interested, but generally speaking the number of spanning trees of a connected graph (else we speak of spanning forests) is given by the order of the jacobian group of the graph. It can be computed by putting the reduced laplacian of the graph in Smith normal form and then multiplying the diagonal entries. In the case of 2 graphs joined by a vertex, the jacobian group is the direct product of the individual groups. When joined by an edge I think the order is $m\cdot n -1$ if $m$ and $n$ are the size of the 2 cycles. More generally, if the two cycles are joined by $k$ different and consecutive edges, this order is $n\cdot m - k^2$ (to be verified)